# delay a for loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, delay

I want to delay a "for loop" for a while but don't know how to do it.

For example. Let's say this "for loop" runs from 0 to 8 and after each i there should be a delay for 2 sek.

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++{
  do something...
  wait for 2 sek. and go on with i=i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the details of what you're actually trying to achieve?  It's likely that you'll want to use setTimeout but it's hard to say without knowing your aim.

Comment: That's not possible in JS. You have to play with functions and use `setTimeout`.

Comment: I guess that this thread answers what you are asking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to go that way:

```js
function jsHello(i) {
    if (i < 0) return;

    setTimeout(function () {

        alert("Hello " + i);

        jsHello(--i);

    }, 2000);
}

jsHello(5);
```

or

```js
function jsHello(i) {
    alert("Hello " + i);

    if (--i > -1) {
      setTimeout(function () { jsHello(i); }, 2000);
    }
}

jsHello(5);
```

Answer (score 5):

Javascript doesn't have a wait command. The way to get this behavior is using `setTimeout`:

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
   do_something(i);
}

function do_something(j) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      tasks to do;
  }, 2000 * j);
}
```

Every time the function `do_something()` is called, it executes *"tasks to do"* scheduled by `2000*i` milliseconds.

Comment: you have syntax error in your code, plus as a result you will have set of timeouts but inside all timeout callbacks i will be equal to 8

Comment: You are right. I'll modify it.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this task you have to use closure -  immediately invoke function witch be called on every iteration with `i` as param, and setTimeout inside this function. In this case param you passed will be stored in scope and could be used in timeout callback:

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) (function(t) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
   //do anything with t 
  }, t*2000)
}(i))
```

**UPD**

Also here is a shorten ES6 version. As `let` has block scope you can get rid os wrap function closure use

```
for (let i=0; i<8; i++){
   setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)
  }, 2000 * i);
}
```

Comment: Although it might add a great amount of delay for N loops, it was the easiest way